# Pattern matching using regex in Scala

Tags: regex, scala

I have a dataset that looks like this :-

```
192.10.678.234  192.12.898.123  public
192.10.567.6    3.3.3.3 public
192.20.123.39   123.34.31.678   private
```

I am stuck on how to match the three fields using pattern matching and regex in
scala as in the second line the "public" field is shifted towards left in the dataset.

Comment: Just  do `line.split("\s+")`, no need to over think this one.

Comment: Why not use [`val Pattern = """^(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)$""".r`](http://ideone.com/0VhnH0)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a rather nasty regex that deals with it: `(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})\s+(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})\s+(private|public)`

Using [kantan.regex](https://github.com/nrinaudo/kantan.regex), you can express the whole thing as follows:

```
import kantan.regex.implicits._

// Where `input` is your string.
input.unsafeEvalRegex[(String, String, String)](rx"(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})\s+(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})\s+(private|public)")
```

This yields an `Iterator[(String, String, String)]` that, when ran through `foreach(println _)`, results in:

```
(192.10.678.234,192.12.898.123,public)
(192.10.567.6,3.3.3.3,public)
(192.20.123.39,123.34.31.678,private)
```

If you're interested in better types (say, an `Entry` class for each entry, representing each IP address in a dedicated type and having `public` and `private` as an ADT), let me know and I can amend the code to deal with that as well - the whole point of kantan.regex is to extract well typed data from strings through regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

[see demo](https://regex101.com/r/uK1yF2/1)

`(?:(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\s*){2}([a-z]+)`

Comment: I require three different fields to match for one row not two fields as in your case